# Join other table to get count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table contains items:

**items**: id, body, user_id

and second table constains votes:

**items_votes**: id, item_id, type

I getting all items by simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM items
```

**How I can get votes count for every item in this query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this...

```
select item.id, item.type, item.user_id, count(*)
FROM items item inner join
items_votes iv on item.id = iv.item_id
group by item.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33d10/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select i.id, i.type, i.user_id, count(*)
FROM items i,items_votes v WHERE i.id = v.item_id
group by i.id
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e7bb/12)